# What can i do for handlebars each not work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

(node:10148) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: req.render is not a function
at E:\desktop\Node.js learn project\node.jsBlog\nodejsBlogProject\routes\main.js:12:13
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:10148) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10148) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

main.js ;

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Post = require('../models/Post')

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('site/index')
})

router.get('/blog', (req, res) => {

    Post.find({}).then(posts => {
        req.render('site/blog', {posts:Post})
    });
    res.render('site/blog');
});

router.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    res.render('site/contact')
})

router.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('site/about')
})

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('site/login')
})

router.get('/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('site/register')
})

module.exports = router
```

app.js;

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')


const app = express()
const port = 3000
const hostname = '127.0.0.1'
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')


mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/nodeblog_db', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true
});

app.use(express.static('assets'))

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs())
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

const main = require('./routes/main')
const posts = require('./routes/posts') 
app.use('/', main)
app.use('/posts', posts)

app.listen(port , hostname, () => {
    console.log(`server working now, http://${hostname}:${port}/`)
})
```

posts.js;

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Post = require('../models/Post')

router.get('/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render('site/addPost')
})

router.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    Post.create(req.body)
    res.redirect('/')
})

module.exports = router
```

Post.js;

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, require:true},
    content: { type: String, require: true},
    date: { type: Date , default: Date.now}
})

module.exports  = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema)
```

I am using mongodb as database. I get this error when I try to use each command in blog.handlebars.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```js
req.render('site/blog', {posts:Post})
```

You wrote `req` when it should be `res`. The value that you pass to `posts` is also incorrect, you're passing the `Post` model but should use the `posts` you get from the callback. Finally, you potentially call `res.render` twice, once in the callback function and a second time afterwards. It makes more sense to call it in the case of a failure, e.g. the database call failed.

Put together it might look like this:

```js
router.get('/blog', (req, res) => {

    Post.find({}).then(posts => {
        res.render('site/blog', { posts: posts });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.render('site/blog');
    });
});
```